# Grab JSON image in custom search

Tags: javascript, json, google-custom-search

how do i grab the image from a Custom search JSON response?

```
  function hndlr(response) {
  for (var i = 0; i < response.items.length; i++) {
    var item = response.items[i];
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += "<br>" + item.htmlTitle;
  }
}
```

for example, i already have 10 results, every article having a title, description and image.

I have already connected to the API with my key and CX code, accessed the htmlTitle, or link or other components. but i dont know how to access the thumbnail part where my image is bound to each result.

this is the response from google custom search:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=101MuxGd8oyOAYvfNthuW7saNpm-m3kSe

**How do i access thumbnail.src?**

item.pagemap.thumbnail.src???

Thanks for your help

Comment: you want to display the image from your JSON?

Comment: sorry if i didnt explained myself, i want to access the image through javascript. like this?:

document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += "<br>" + item.thumbnail.src;

Comment: make sure you place item.thumbnail.src in an  image tags src  if you want to display it

Comment: thats fair, but item.thumbnail.src is undefined XD, so that sintax is not correct:
item.pagemap.thumbnail.src or item.thumbnail.src or any other sintax is undefined. im struggling with that sintax when i try to get the src string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as `thumbnail` is an array of objects, you can access it on the following way if `item` is an element from the `items` array:

```
item.pagemap.thumbnail[0].src
```

where `item.pagemap.thumbnail[0]` is the first object from the `thumbnail` array.

To make it more bulletproof you should check the array length before fetching the first element from it and also that the `src` attribute is exist or not. For example:

```
var fallbackImage = 'the url for the fallback image';
var thumbnail = item.pagemap.thumbnail.length > 0 ? item.pagemap.thumbnail[0].src || fallbackImage : fallbackImage;
```

Comment: yeah, item.pagemap.thumbnail[0].src worked great. And i will definetely will check for a fallback image when image is not in the JSON code.thank you,

Comment: Why do i get "Unexpected token :" error when using this sintax in javascript:
item.metatags[0].og:image

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1pD9oTRdrqLkZk1mmn4Zx0Vr0c5wGm58y

Comment: i mean, item.pagemap.cse_image[0].src gets the trick done, but whenever the custom search api finds an undefined value, the code just break. For example, item.pagemap.cse_image[0].src or  item.pagemap.thumbnail[0].src is not always present, so i get and undefined error, how can i put a default image BEFORE the undefined message?

Comment: For your first question this will do the trick: `item.metatags[0]['og:image']. About the 2nd: if you use `item.pagemap.thumbnail[0].src || fallbackImage` it will return the fallbackImage if the first part returns false. And of course it will return false if the src is undefined. Try it :)

Comment: WHEN i use   var image = item.metatags[0]['og:image'];     i get "Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

Comment: this is my code: ----  
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1sevR7_wvZo8Nnykc-zymlgv547sxYCrF    -----  For example, when i click Nextpage, it breaks, then i click nextpage again, and it pass to the 3r page correctly. second page is never reach bcoz of the error. BTW, thanks for ur help (y)

Comment: problem solved, i used your code in the answer to do the fallback image, thank you @peetya